# C# unsubscribe from timer event not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
[Inject]
public Timer timer { get; set; }

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    settingsModel = applicationDb.SettingsModal.FirstOrDefault();
    updateInfo();
}

public async void updateInfo()
{
    try
    {
        if (settingsModel.Message != "" && settingsModel.Message != null)
        {
            timer.Elapsed -= (w, e) => timer_Elapsed(w,e);
            timer.Elapsed += (w, e) => timer_Elapsed(w, e);          
            timer.Interval = 3000;
            timer.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            timer.Elapsed -= (w, e) => timer_Elapsed(w, e);

            timer.Stop();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ToastService.ShowError(e.Message);
    }
}

async void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{       
    // do some stuff
}
```

The problem is unsubscribe not working on this line

```
timer.Elapsed -= new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
```

Each time the `UpdateInfo` method gets called, the event `timer.Elapsed` gets more sub

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to the method instead of an anonymous function.

```
// Subscribe
timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed; 

// Unsubscribe
timer.Elapsed -= timer_Elapsed;
```

From this page on [subscribing to events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events).

> If you don't have to unsubscribe from an event later, you can use the addition assignment operator (+=) to attach an anonymous function as an event handler.

> You cannot easily unsubscribe from an event if you used an anonymous function to subscribe to it.

> We recommend that you don't use anonymous functions to subscribe to events if you have to unsubscribe from the event at some later point in your code.

Comment: Tried it, unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: You're using timers in a web service, of course it won't work. Use async code like a normal person, that's why `Task.Delay` exists. What @hijinxbassist says is correct, that's how you use timers in applications with normal life cycles (normal console or windowed applications), you're just using them in the wrong place for the wrong reason.

Comment: sorry, i didn't now that is not working in web ,, thanks for help